# Inversion of control on Compact Framework 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, .net-2.0, compact-framework2.0

I've been "googling" around about inversion of control on Compact Framework but most of solutions will work on 3.5 version.

Summarizing: I need a light-weight, simple inversion of control container working on Compact Framework 2.0.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems, the current versions of most IoC containers don't support old versions of the .net framework (and the Compact Framework) anymore.

You might get away with using older releases.
For example, the [Ninject download page](http://ninject.org/download) says that Ninject 1.5 works on CF 2.0:

> **Older Version (version 1.5)**
>
> Support for versions of the .NET Framework prior to 3.5 was
>   discontinued in Ninject 2.0. If you need backwards compatibility, you
>   can still use [Ninject 1.5](http://github.com/ninject/ninject1/). However, this version is only receiving
>   critical bug fixes, and all new development is being done on the
>   Ninject 2.0 codebase. Please only use this if you need to!
>
> Binaries:
>
> - .NET Framework 3.5
> - .NET Framework 2.0
> - .NET Compact Framework 3.5
> - [.NET Compact Framework 2.0](http://github.com/downloads/ninject/ninject1/Ninject-1.5.0.0-release-netcf-2.0.zip)
> - Silverlight 2.0
> - Silverlight 3.0
> - Mono 2.0

Comment: Good answer and it's understandable that older versions of .NET and CF aren't supported anymore, becuase 2.0 version is far enough to be discarded in new developments and third-party products' versions. I'll give a try to Ninject 1.5. I was looking for Castle Windsor, but it's impossible to get it in CF, since it uses Reflection Emit and that's not supported in CF. Thanks for the resarch.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another decent solution: [OpenNETCF.IoC Framework on codeplex](http://ioc.codeplex.com)